# django datepickup form widget work only on one field

Tags: django, forms

I not sure if I did misconfiguration, but in my form datepickup widget working only on one field (t_start). Widget on t_end not working.
I don't have clue what caused this issue, maybe someone had similar issue in the past?

And question,
How to selected name in form combine with id in database and this id add to filter in query, for example sourcetype_id__in=[3] replace (3) with variables list.

my forms

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm, DateField, DateInput
from platforms.models import Platforms, Sources

class TimeSelection(forms.Form):
    t_start = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'id': 'datepicker'}))
    t_end = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'id': 'datepicker'}))

class PlatformSelection(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Platforms
    platforms = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Platforms.objects.all(), required=False)

class SourceSelection(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Sources
    sources = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Sources.objects.filter(pk__in=[1, 3]), required=False)
```

views

```
def queryset(request):
    t_start = None
    t_end = None
    platform = None
    source = None
    t_form = TimeSelection()
    p_form = PlatformSelection()
    s_form = SourceSelection()
    if request.method == "POST":
        t_form = TimeSelection(request.POST)
        p_form = PlatformSelection(request.POST)
        s_form = SourceSelection(request.POST)
        if t_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid() and s_form.is_valid():
            t_start = t_form.cleaned_data.get('t_start')
            t_end = t_form.cleaned_data.get('t_end')
            platform = p_form.cleaned_data.get('platforms')
            source = s_form.cleaned_data.get('sources')
    else:
        t_form = TimeSelection()
        p_form = PlatformSelection()
        s_form = SourceSelection()
    data = Events.objects.filter(platform_id__in=[7,8], sourcetype_id__in=[3], event_datetime__range=(t_start, t_end))
    return render_to_response('platforms.html', {'t_form': t_form,
                                                 'p_form': p_form,
                                                 's_form': s_form,
                                                 'data': data,
                                                 't_start': t_start,
                                                 'platform': platform,
                                                 'source': source,
                                                 't_end': t_end,
                                                 },
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

my forms looks like:

```
<form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ p_form.as_table }}
  {{ s_form.as_table }}
  {{ t_form }}
  <input type="submit" value="Show Charts">  
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that you have same `id` for date input widget `'id': 'datepicker'` change it to different ids and date picker should work. Remember in DOM [ids must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#adef-id).